# ¿Cómo eliminar una parte del principio de una cadena (linea de log)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Quiero emplear `str.split` para poder eliminar una parte del principio de registros logs pero no me termino de aclarar.

Tengo como entrada logs con este formato:

> eeuu,oregon,31224,2017/04/01,26,164.123.40.6,monday,...

Como salida espero poder quitar de todas las lineas los primeros 3 campos que pueden ser distintos a los arriba presentados:

> 2017/04/01,26,164.123.40.6,monday,...

Con `text.split(",")` puedo separar los campos en una lista pero no se como conseguir de vuelta la cadena con los tres primeros eliminados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu entrada es un string (`str`) una forma general es con `str.split` + slicing de listas + `str.join`. En tu caso hay una forma mas eficiente usando solo `split` (ver segunda parte de la respuesta).

```
>>> log = "eeuu,oregon,31224,2017/04/01,26,164.123.40.6,monday"

>>> new_log = ",".join(log.split(",")[3:])
>>> print(new_log)
2017/04/01,26,164.123.40.6,monday
```

La explicación es la siguiente:

- `split(",")` retorna una lista resultado de partir la cadena donde se encuentre el carácter ",".
- `[3:]` hace un rebanado de la lista, toma desde el tercer item hasta el final.
- `",".join` crea una nueva cadena concatenado cada elemento de la lista anterior e insertando "," entre cada item.

---

Hay una forma mas eficiente y concisa que es usando el parámetro `maxsplit` de [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> log = "eeuu,oregon,31224,2017/04/01,26,164.123.40.6,monday"

>>> new_log = log.split(",",  3)[3]
>>> print(new_log)
2017/04/01,26,164.123.40.6,monday
```

De esta forma le indicamos a `split` que solo parta la cadena hasta la tercera coma. El resto de la cadena queda sin partir como último elemento de la lista retornada por `split`.

Esta última forma es la que debes usar en tu caso, la primera (split+slicing+join) es útil cuando queremos eliminar partes a ambos lados o en el interior de la cadena. En tu caso solo quieres eliminar al inicio.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que buscaba.